# PHP while loop issue with float left elements

Tags: php, html, css

I am having some issues when using a container with float left items , the thing is that im while looping them from db along with another div that is the modal popup which is using **display:none;**

```
while($fe = $projects->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

$var = $fe['id'];
echo '
    <div class="portfolio-item" id="zd_'.$var.'" style="background:url('.$fe['imagem'].')no-repeat center;">
    <div class="portfolio-item-banner">
            <p>'.$fe['titulo'].'</p>
            <p>'.$fe['category'].'</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    ';  

// Modal 

echo '    
    <div id="modala" class="zp_'.$var.'">
            <div class="modal-left">
              <img src="'.$fe['imagem'].'" width="90%" height="480px" />
            </div>
            <div class="modal-right">
                <div class="modal-i" ><img class="close_'.$var.'"  src="templates/fabrico/images/cross.svg" height="15px"  style="margin-top:34px;"></div>
                <div class="modal-x">
                    <br>
                    <h1 style="color:#a22427;">Worksheet</h1><br>

                    <h4>CONTRACT X</h4>

                    <h4>BLABLABLA</h4><br>

                    <h4>CLIENT</h4>
                    <p>testtest</p><br>

                    <h4>LOCATION</h4>
                    <p>testtest</p><br>

                    <h4>DESCRIPTION</h4>
                    <p>testtest</p><br>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>    
     '; 
}
```

What is happening is that the first 4 items go good with float left but the others simply disapear from the screen making it look like the float left element is not working properly, however if i remove the popup #modala  from the loop they show up good

This is the output HTML

---

I fixed this , made another while loop below this one only for modals as seems like modals were displaying after the item so it ruined the flow

Comment: It doesn't sound like this problem has anything to do with the PHP, but rather with the generated HTML/CSS rules. It might be much more instructive to see the generated result and style rules.

Comment: you can't really use a static id in your loop `<div id="modala"`

Comment: 2 things, 1. is `$fe['id']` from 4th loop have any double quotes or wild character 2. `id="modala"` -> id should be unique in a page.

Comment: can't recreate behavior with information given [codepen](https://codepen.io/dreitzner/pen/yqKXyg)

Comment: I just added the output html to the original post

Comment: They still display properly on my end... :)